# Rename files written to zip file using Zipfile module python

Tags: python, zip

How can I change the file name for files added to the zip file without affecting the original file?

```
with ZipFile('myZip.zip', 'w') as zipObj2:
     for file in filelist:
         zipObj2.write(file)
```

I want the file names to be random and not the actual name. So something like

```
with ZipFile('myZip.zip', 'w') as zipObj2:
     for file in filelist:
         file.rename(os.urandom(10).hex())
         zipObj2.write(file)
```

Comment: Take a look on `arcname` argument of [`ZipFile.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ZipFile.write` method takes a second argument, `arcname`, which is the name of the file inside the archive. So something like:

```
for file in filelist:
    zipObj2.write(file, os.urandom(10).hex())
```

would add the file with a random name.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: Do you know if this module is standard module in python or is to be installed using pip?